# Remote access to second router (router in cascade / Serial)

Tags: networking, router, remote-access

The installation is in a holidays house (so no permanent internet access)
I have a 4g-Routerm (ROUTER-1 = huawei B525-b23) that enable the internet access. I switch it on one day a week.
I have another router (ROUTER-2 = GL-MT300N-V2).

ROUTER-2 is always plugged on electricity.
On ROUTER-2 is connected through ethernet port a Raspberry-Pi3 (with Home Assistant on it).
On ROUTER-2 is connected through WIFI a Camera IP

ROUTER-1 and ROUTER-2 are connected together through ethernet.

When ROUTER-1 is not plug to electricity, none have acces to internet, but it's not an issue.

The camera save picture on the Rapbery Pi3, the Home Assistat is recording some sensor data.

When I switch on the electricity on the ROUTER-1, everyone have access to internet.

What I want is to have remote Access to my router-2 and my Rasberry and my Camera when ROUTER-1 is online

How should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into 'Port Forwarding'. You need to set up port forward rules so that you can make unsolicited connections to devices behind a router. As you have two routers you would need to set the rules up twice. Once on the outer router, then again on the inner router.

You may either:

- Forward ports for individual services you need, such as HTTP/HTTPS for managing your router, SSH on your raspberry pi, the camera protocol for your camera. This is somewhat insecure as these devices would be exposed directly to the internet. People will (not might, will!) try to connect to your devices and guess the passwords.
- Forward a port for a single remote access service that you use to connect to all other devices on your network, such as SSH tunneling or OpenVPN. This is more secure. You can use pre-exchanged authentication keys instead of passwords. You are also using known, open source, robust, and industry trusted software to protect your network from being infiltrated. You can run either of these services from your existing raspberry pi assuming you have shell access to the system to install more applications over Home Assistant. Otherwise you might need another raspberry pi with any distribution of Linux on it.

Comment: you suggested adding more hardware too will downvote when i can

Comment: i wouldnt advise using the first option and opening up ports on your router willy nilly due to the obvious security issues that might arise from lets say having ssh port forwarded over http. misguided answer.

Comment: I suggested he might need new hardware depending on how software I know nothing about may or may not work. In any case, buying things was only one of the reasons I voted you down. There are other factual errors in your answer.